# Error while reading a compressed csv file using Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, gzip

I am getting an error while reading a compressed csv file.
The error is as below:
"zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing: invalid distances set"

Code :

```
filename = 'testfile.gz'
with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        print(line)
```

I tried gunzip on the file and it worked without any issues.
I used gunzip -t . It gave rc 0.

Comment: What exact version of Python is this? See [zlib: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back](//stackoverflow.com/q/40652405). That said, I don't think this was ever present in Python 2.7.

Comment: $ python --version
Python 2.7.5

Comment: Can you provide a link to the gzip file?

Comment: Sorry i cannot provide you the file as i am not the owner of the file. Please find the additional info : On linux machine 1 (python 2.7.6/zlib 1.2.7) it was failing with the above error but on linux machine 2 (python 2.7.11/zlib 1.2.8) it was successful. Which one might be causing the issue? Python or Zlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one seems like a bug in zlib library with version 1.2.7-15

```
$ rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
```

I got it updated to 1.2.7-17 and the issue got resolved.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64
```